# Do while loop not exiting

Tags: c#, do-while

A quick question about C#. I have shown my code below, I cannot not work out why the loop will never close, the `Do While` loop should close when the user enters "A" or "B" etc, may sound like a stupid question I'm just starting C#

```
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("What one would you like to buy? A B C or D");
    a = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine(a);
} while (a != 'A' || a != 'B' || a != 'C' || a != 'D');
```

Comment: You want `&&` instead of `||`.  If `a == 'A'` then `a != 'B'` and the loop continues.  If `a == 'B'` then `a != 'A'` and the loop continues.  No matter what `a` is, one of those expressions will be true making the whole condition true and the loop will continue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use "&&" instead of "||" since you want to exit when you DO NOT enter a, b, c, or d. Currently it will continue to run forever, since a is always either not 'a' or not 'b'.

Comment: The idea is that it should only exit if the user Enters "A" "B" "C" or "D" if they don't the loop should continue to run.

Comment: If the user enters "A", they've entered a letter that's not equal to "B", "C", or "D", so the test in your loop is always true.

Comment: @Adam - or you can turn the `!=` into `==`

Comment: @Adam -- Matt is still right  You need to use `&&` because you want to say "if not equal to A *and* not equal to B *and* not equal to C *and* not equal to D, then keep looping"

Answer (score 4):

Besides fixing your issue, I suggest you go for a safer and clearer approach, as your code throws an exception if the user enters more or less than one character, and also forces the user to press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

With this code the user just needs to press one key and it doesn't matter if it's uppercase or lowercase:

```
char a;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Which one would you like to buy? A B C or D");
    a = Char.ToUpper(Console.ReadKey().KeyChar);
    Console.WriteLine();
} while (!"ABCD".Contains(a));
```

Comment: Can you explain why it is safer and clearer ?   a == 'A'  is clearer than  !"A...".Contains(a)  and more efficient...

Comment: @Didier68: Safer because a user can type "aa" and hit enter (in the original code), which would cause `Convert.ToChar` to throw a `FormatException`. Using `ReadKey` ensures you are only ever looking at 1 character.

Comment: @Didier68: Cleaner (with the `!"ABCD".Contains(a)`) is debatable, but I doubt there is any substantial difference in performance in a loop that requires a user to hit a key.

Comment: I said nothing about efficiency, anyway spending a few milliseconds more is more than welcome if the code is easier to read and maintain. If tomorrow there are more options, it's much easier to add them here than with the original approach. And forcing the user to press ENTER is so 1990. :P

Answer (score 1):

replace the OR condition by AND ( && ) !
Because if you type an 'A', (a == 'A'), then "a != 'B'" is true and the OR condition is TRUE...

Comment: We are giving the solution in the same time ! When i begin my answer, there are no other

Answer (score 0):

You should use && in your condition.
You want your loop to stop when user either enters A or B in upper or lower case.In order words you want to continue only when what user entered is not A and not B(in upper or lower case)

Comment: There was no answer when I started answering, you might have posted while I was drafting my answer.